# "Playing With Characters" Hackerrank Question in C

Tags: c

I am having trouble knowing the issue about this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() 
{
    char ch, s[50], sen[100];
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    scanf("%s", s);
    scanf("%[^\n]s",sen);

    printf("%c\n", ch);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    printf("%s", sen);
}
```

With the input and desired output of

```
C
Hello
Hello World
```

The programs has an observed output of

```
c
Hello
4��,�
```

This program is supposed to output a character, a string, and a sentence from the user, but the sentence that the user writes is not correctly shown by the program.

Comment: When you ask a question, you should also describe the problem.  Sayings "it seems that there is a problem" isn't adequate.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem, an exact copy of the observed output, and a sample of the output desired instead. State what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: `%[` and `%s` are two separate specifiers, you do **not** combine them as `%[]s`.

Comment: You cannot use `scanf()` correctly unless you **check the return**. You cannot use `%s` or `%[...]` correctly unless you provide a *field-width* modifier to protect your array bound, e.g. `%49s` and `%99[^\n]`. That is why new C programmers (and in fact all C programmers) are encouraged to use `fgets()` to read all user input. Then simply parse as needed with `sscanf()` or walking a pair of pointers or using something like `strtok()` or `strcspn()`, etc...

Comment: No `<string.h>`, `<math.h>` or `<stdlib.h>` required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%s", s)` reads *up until the next whitespace* (not including that whitespace). Which means the first unread character is the newline after `Hello`.

`scanf("%[^\n]s",sen)` encounters that newline first. `%[` matches a *non-empty* sequence of characters. Since the first character already fails to match, `%[` fails.<sup>[1]</sup>

If you would check the return value of your `scanf()`s -- **as you always should** -- you would realize that the `scanf()` returns `0` due to that matching failure. Thus, `sen` never gets initialized, making the subsequent `printf` of `sen` undefined behavior.

The generic advice for reading and parsing user input is to read full lines using `fgets()` and then parsing that in memory using much less fragile functions like `strchr`, `strspn`, `strtol` etc. etc.

If you **insist** on using `*scanf()` functions, *always check the return value*.

---

[1]: As @oka pointed out, that `s` at the end there also does not do what you likely expected it to do. It matches a literal `s` in the input.